# Which GTK+ elements support which CSS properties?

Tags: python, css, gtk

While applying my own CSS to my GTK+ application, I noticed, that some elements ignore some CSS properties and others ignore others or don't ignore them, which leads me to search for an overview of which elements support which CSS properties.

So far I couldn't find any such overview.

For example `Gtk.Label` doesn't support `border` at all, I had to put a `Gtk.Frame` around it and style that in the CSS file. Another issue is, that even a `Gtk.Frame` doesn't support `margin`, which I want to use.

Can anyone give me some direction on where to find that?
(Or if I am mistaken with all of this, how do I make the elements support CSS properties?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ptomato/0fb634ef4098bb89026f) is an overview of which CSS properties are supported as of GTK 3.8. The same information is mostly contained in the documentation for [`GtkCssProvider`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html#GtkCssProvider.description), albeit not in table form.

Which widgets support which properties is a bit harder. It boils down to two kinds of widgets: those that are simple and only support basic styling (no borders or backgrounds), such as `GtkLabel`; and those that support all properties, such as `GtkFrame`. Wrapping a simple widget inside a `GtkFrame` or `GtkEventBox`, as you have discovered, is the usual way to turn one into the other.

The `margin` property is not supported at all, and I'm told that this is a choice by the GTK developers. The thinking goes, as I understand it, that GTK is not HTML, and the layout of your widgets on screen should be governed by your code and not by CSS.

**Update in GTK 3.20**: The `margin` CSS property is now supported across most or all widgets.

Comment: That's strange. I remember clearly, that I found the margin property on some of the GTK+ pages (on the very page you linked, which I already looked at before). Maybe they removed it in more recent versions?


Padding on the other hand seems to be ok ... So if I was to do a workaround I could wrap everything in a frame and then use padding in that frame. Disabling only margin and not padding doesn't enforce what you've described.


Maybe that's worth a new question?: How to make the widgets inside of a Gtk.Grid keep a margin to the Grid containing container? (without dirty workarounds)

Comment: [`margin` does exist in GTK as a widget property,](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--margin) that you have to set in your code. It has never been supported (yet) as a CSS property. I _believe_ the reasoning is that padding (e.g., in a `GtkButton`, in between the border and contents of the button) is a style property of the widget that should be specified in CSS, whereas the margin between widgets is part of the layout that should be done in code.

Comment: You are correct about it having to be set in the code. I still don't really understand that design decision, since now I have to manage CSS and in code layout information, instead of only CSS, but I guess, I'll simply have to deal with it. Maybe in some later version it'll change.

Comment: ...huh? GTK+ has supported CSS `margin` properties since the very start of its CSS era (circa 2012?), AFAICT, and the developers very much **do** advise setting them in the CSS, not in application source code. Your own `gist` shows this. Having said that, I got here by searching for info around some inconsistencies I seem to be finding in CSS `margin`s - such as not being applied on the `widget` CSS node of `EventBox`es - so it's possible that you and/or the OP hit a bug/quirk like this and drew your conclusions from that.

Comment: That's not correct. Until GTK 3.20, released a year after I posted the above, `margin` was _parsed_ ("supported" in that it was not a syntax error to include it in your CSS, and why it appears in the gist which I distilled from the source code), but had no effect on any regular GTK widgets. You could write custom widgets that respected it, though.

Comment: However, they changed their thinking in the meantime and made most or all widgets respect `margin` when they stabilized the CSS API in GTK 3.20. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @ptomato I came here after finding your other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33840289/2757035) to say 'oops, I see what you meant now' :) Thanks for the clarification and the update. Next I suppose I'm responsible for making `EventBox` handle margins... joy :P