# GTK+ Css ignoring margin

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtk#

I am setting a margin in a css style file, but GTK seems to be ignoring it.
The background color works fine, but the margin only works if I set it from code.

```
#Widget {
    background: #00F000;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I am not sure why it would ignore the margin rule but honor the background one.
If I set the margin from code it works correctly.

Comment: I noticed this problem also when trying to set margin myself, it seems that both margin and padding are not yet working.. (or it is implemented for a very limited set of widgets which seems strange)

Comment: In case someone else stumbles accross this, I found the answer https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2015/11/20/a-gtk-update/ From this Q/A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838757/can-i-style-gtkbox-margin-padding-with-css-only